# Post a POJO to a PHP application using Retrofit

Tags: php, retrofit

I am trying to send a POJO via a POST request through Retrofit to a PHP application and I wish to have the fields received via PHP's $_POST variable. This seems easy but I can't seem to get it to work.

My retrofit interface:

```
public interface APIMethods {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/api/postUser/")
    void postUser(
            @Query("auth_token") String auth_token,
            @Body User user,
            Callback<RESTResponse> callback
    );
}
```

The request went through without errors but $_POST is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, based on Victory's suggestion of FieldMap.

Interface:

```
public interface APIMethods {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/api/postUser/")
    void postUser(
            @Header("auth_token") String auth_token,
            @FieldMap Map<String, String> userFields,
            Callback<RESTResponse> callback
    );
}
```

To convert a User POJO to `Map<String, String>` FieldMap, I used [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)'s ObjectMapper:

```
// Get a REST adapter
RestAdapter restAdapter = RestAdapterFactory.getInstance();
// Create API instance
IAPIMethods methods = restAdapter.create(IAPIMethods.class);

    // Define callback
    Callback<RESTResponse> callback = new Callback<RESTResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(RESTResponse restResponse, Response response) {
            String res = restResponse.responseText;
            if(restResponse.status != 1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error: " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                textView.setText(res);
            }

            Log.d("Debug", res);

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("RetrofitError", error.toString());
        }
    };

// Instantiate User object/bean
User user = new User();
// Set user properties
user.username = "...";
...

// Instantiate Jackson's ObjectMapper to convert User POJO to Map<String, String>
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> userFields = mapper.convertValue(user, Map.class);
methods.postUser(API_KEY, userFields, callback);
```

In PHP, access user data with $_POST and Headers with getallheaders();

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `@Field` annotation to set the key value pair for `@FormUrlEncode` to send.

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("/")
 void example(@Field("foo") String name, @Field("bar") String occupation);
 }
```

[official docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Field.html)

There is also the very handy [FieldMap](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/FieldMap.html)

Comment: Thank you Victory. FieldMap seems more efficient for me but how will I convert my POJO to a FieldMap without handpicking properties?